# how to assign menu control to sub-node of sitemap on masterpage

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, aspmenu-control

i am using menu controls on my master-page and have used sitemap data-source to populate it. It shows main node on menu. is there a way that it populates the menu with sub-nodes of my master node rather than using default "home" ie masternode as starting menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create a site map, you always design your properties in a way that it suites your web needs, They will contain, your starting node, name display, view state and autopostback. 
Check your sipemapdatasource properties and your will know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You just simply put the ShowStartingNode = False in the SiteMapDataSource properties.
IT was simpler than i thoght.